# Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled. node_modules\react-idle-timer\dist\index.esm.js:

Tags: reactjs

`Not able to build reactjs project on teamcity server.

However able to build in local machine.

Starting: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script1225311399053976363.cmd

[17:04:39] :     [Step 6/9] in directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c162750c8d2e0bb8\reactjs

[17:04:40] :     [Step 6/9] > reactjs@4.7.1 build:dev

D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c162750c8d2e0bb8\reactjs

[17:04:40] :     [Step 6/9] > env-cmd -f .env.dev craco build

[17:04:44] :     [Step 6/9] Creating an optimized production build...

[17:04:49]W:     [Step 6/9] Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:

[17:04:49]W:     [Step 6/9] npx browserslist@latest --update-db

[17:04:49]W:     [Step 6/9]
[17:04:49]W:     [Step 6/9] Why you should do it regularly:

[17:04:49]W:     [Step 6/9] https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating

[17:07:29] :     [Step 6/9] Failed to compile.

[17:07:29] :     [Step 6/9] ./node_modules/react-idle-timer/dist/index.esm.js

[17:07:29] :     [Step 6/9] SyntaxError: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\c162750c8d2e0bb8\reactjs\node_modules\react-idle-
timer\dist\index.esm.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (1:6658):

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.

[17:07:30]W:     [Step 6/9] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

[17:07:30]W:     [Step 6/9] npm ERR! errno 1

[17:07:30]W:     [Step 6/9] npm ERR! reactjs@4.7.1 build:dev: `env-cmd -f .env.dev craco build`

[17:07:30]W:     [Step 6/9] npm ERR! Exit status 1

[17:07:30]W:     [Step 6/9] npm ERR!

[17:07:30]W:     [Step 6/9] npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs@4.7.1 build:dev script.

[17:07:30]W:     [Step 6/9] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

[17:07:30]W:     [Step 6/9]

[17:07:30]W:     [Step 6/9] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

[17:07:30]W:     [Step 6/9] npm ERR!
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2023-08-11T17_07_30_032Z-debug.log
[17:07:30]W:     [Step 6/9] Process exited with code 1
[17:07:30]E:     [Step 6/9] Process exited with code 1 (Step: React_Build (Command Line))
[17:07:30]E:     [Step 6/9] Step React_Build (Command Line) failed
in local machne am able to build using npm run build:dev. Not able to figure out whats the issue. Need suggestion.`